# Are the square brackets in Clojure's defn, defmacro and binding really a vector?

Tags: syntax, vector, clojure

Are the square brackets around arguments in Clojure's `defn`, `defmacro` and `binding` (am I forgetting some?) really creating a vector or is it just a matter of syntax, making the arguments stand out from the rest?

I'm reading Clojure in Action which states:

> Clojure uses vectors to denote
>   function arguments or binding forms.

which made me ask this question here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is really a vector.  We can see that by building a function manually and then evaluating it:

```
(eval (list (list 'fn (vector 'x) (list '* 'x 2)) 100))
;=> 200
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: One question though (after two and a half years...), why isn't this accepted? (defn foo (vector 'x 'y) (+ x y))

Comment: The `defn` form is a macro so at the time it's examined (macroexpansion time) nothing has been evaluated. So when it looks at the binding form it expects a vector but instead sees a list `(vector (quote x) (quote y))`.

Comment: Ah, I have been macro'd again. Tnx.